# Open new Activity when clicking a button

Tags: java, android, button, cordova

I would like to know how to open a new activity when you click a button. I know there are many answers on the web, but none of them work and when I add the code to open the new activity, I may have no errors in Eclipse, but when I open he app on my emulator, or on my phone, it crashes..

Here's the MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my actiity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Here's my fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTV"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Radio" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRadio"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="News" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:onClick="openNewActivity"
        android:text="Live TV" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my TVActivity.java:

```
package com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class TVActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/tv.html");
    }
}
```

Here's my activity_tv.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp.TVActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Here's my fragment_tv.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp.TVActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.BlueTechnologies.UltimateGreekApp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TVActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: read a tutorial like this http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/210-lesson-9-event-listeners-with-button-example.html

=google is on our side!

Comment: You need to post the output of the LOGCAT to determine what the error is. Also, you seem to be using PhoneGap and aren't just making a standard Android app. Also, most importantly, you're missing the TVActivity from the android-manifest.xml. Copy the one you have there and remove the intent-filter, and it should be good to go.

Comment: Isn't PhoneGap a WebView container where you define the view of your app with HTML5, CSS and the functionality with JavaScript, and the interaction with the android app through a Javascript interface? it's pretty complicated - you should look up some guides and tutorials on how to use PhoneGap if you really are trying to use that rather than just a standard app.

Comment: I am using Phonegap only for the TVActivity, and also, I have put the TVActivity into AndroidManifest.xml, as you can see above!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add below code to your main activity for each button,,
also "change second activity to your needed activity"

```
    Button firstButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRadio); 

    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, **SecondActivity**.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

}
}

Comment: The app force closes.. :(